# Looking for help on how to get started with my first programming project

Tags: python-3.x, web-crawler

Step 1: 
Open google chrome to the chess.com website

Step 2: 
Login into my account via the homepage

Step 3: 
Hover mouse cursor over the big “Learn” button on the banner on the left hand side of the web page. This will extend into another menu.

Step 4:
On this menu that has popped up, I will click the button which says “Videos”, which will navigate me to this url: “https://www.chess.com/videos”

Step 5:
Then I click the “Library” button to take me to: “https://www.chess.com/videos/library”

Step 6:
I open up a specific video (out of the many which are in a list) by clicking on the title link.

This is how the list looks like:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/VsxhQH5siigGMMoJA

Step 7:
On the new page, with the video player in plain sight, I right click and then inspect element- in order to enter Chrome development tools
Like so:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/96YgYTfLa58MHSmp7

Step 8:
Then I click the “pointer arrow” button in the top left hand corner of the dev tool box.

Step 9:
Then I “select”  on the video player to highlight it.

Cf. this image:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/6wsLFEzmcBJVJTHJ9

Step 10:

Then I open the .mp4 link which has appeared in the elements tab, which will thus open a new tab which only contains the video player on the screen

Step 11 (Final step):
Then I click the button in the bottom right hand corner and then select “Download” in order to get the .mp4 file.

Cf. this image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/gDMxwmNBSwBCq4LP8

I find it very tedious to do this process of downloading all the embedded videos from a website such as this, because I must actually open a new video in order to get a chance to download it.

Thus, I was thinking of making my very first project as a complete novice programmer (to keep myself motivated!) to try and program something which can automate this process.

My  questions is: Is it possible to automate this algorithm that I have stated above (perhaps with some kind of bot or web crawler), and what topics should I learn about in order to develop the skills in order to do what is necessary?

Thank you so much for the help everyone! I am very grateful :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Using python, all this should be possible using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) (automating browser clicking etc), [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (searching in HTML DOM) and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (downloading video, HTML etc.).

Comment: I agree with @Jeppe ,  learning python is a very good starting point for projects like this =) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize you may not be looking for a code-solution, but I have included one that you can use for inspiration. It downloads all the videos into a directory "chessvideos" (note that there are 123 pages with ~25 videos on each, so it will take a long time to finish).

Building a webcrawler like this is a process. Knowing that you can get the HTML of a url using `requests` and that you can "query" the DOM to find elements using `BeautifulSoup`, open your browser and do the inspections as you mention in your question. E.g which HTML-attributes should you be looking for? Classes, Id's, tags etc.
Part of this process is also to realize how the system will respond to your requests, e.g you mention logging in - this may often be a requirement, but it is not actually for this website, making the problem a lot simpler. Hope it is of some use.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

class ChessDownloader():
    download_directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "chessvideos")

    def __init__(self):
        res = requests.get("https://www.chess.com/videos/library")
        if res.status_code == 200:
            b = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html5lib')
            a = b.find('a', text='Last').get('href')
            pages = int(a.replace('https://www.chess.com/videos/library?page=', '')) # get the number of pages using the "Last" button
            for i in range(pages):
                self.download_videos_from_page(i)

    def download_videos_from_page(self, page_number):
        if page_number == 0:
            res = requests.get('https://www.chess.com/videos/library')
        else:
            res = requests.get('https://www.chess.com/videos/library?page=' + str(page_number))
        if res.status_code == 200:
            b = BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html5lib')
            links = b.find_all('a', { 'class' : 'content-image' })
            links = [a.get('href') for a in links]
            for link in links:
                r = requests.get(link)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features='html5lib')
                    video_url = b.find('meta', {'property': 'og:video:secure_url'}).get('content')
                    self.download_video(video_url)

    def download_video(self, url):
        if not os.path.exists(self.download_directory):
            os.mkdir(self.download_directory)
        res = requests.get(url)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
            file_path = os.path.join(self.download_directory, name)
            if not os.path.exists(file_path): # Dont download if we already have it
                with open(file_path, 'wb+') as f:
                    f.write(res.content)
c = ChessDownloader()
```

Comment: It is necessary to log in before downloading videos otherwise you would be only downloading 3 minute snippets of an actually 15-20 minute video (since users without an account don't get access to the entire video). What would you do to   make the program log into an account first?

Comment: @LucasAldini Ah, I didn't realize that. It may be possible to log in using requests, [read this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/). Otherwise you could have a go with [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). You could reuse some of the code above and replace the `requests.get(URL)` calls with `mydriver.get(URL)` or by clicking through the menus.